# Draw a line between points

Tags: d3.js

Another trivial question. I am trying to draw a line between points, here, starting from lineData[0] to lineData[1], and so on. I am getting a very funny looking area rather than a line! Can you please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Icon </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<p id="drawing">

    <script>

        // data is not same as here, just to explain the requirement created it.
        var lineData = [{"x": 55, "y": 65},
            {"x": 63, "y": 57},
            {"x": 157, "y": 57},
            {"x": 165, "y": 65}];

        var svg = d3.select("#drawing")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("height", 200)
                .attr("width", 200)
                .attr("transform", "translate(20, 20)");

        var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                })
                .interpolate("linear");

        svg.append("path")
                .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
                .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
                .on("mouseover", function () {
                    d3.select(this)
                            .style("stroke", "orange");
                })
                .on("mouseout", function () {
                    d3.select(this)
                            .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)");
                });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're drawing a `<path>`, and you haven't set the path's fill. By default it's black, so you're drawing an object instead. Try removing the fill after appending your `<path>`:

```
svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
        .style("stroke-width", 0.5)
        .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
        .style("fill", "none") // <------ add this line
```

and you get this:

[image: line]